# rust-how to combine this marco with loop/recursive?

Tags: rust

I have some code like this:

```rust
macro_rules! match_token_pattern {
    ($parser:ident, $a:ident) => {{
        let a = $parser.$a();

        if a != None {
            Some(a)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }};

    ($parser:ident, $a:ident, $b:ident) => {{
        let a = $parser.$a();
        let b = $parser.$b();

        if a != None && b != None {
            Some((a, b))
        } else {
            None
        }
    }};

    ($parser:ident, $a:ident, $b:ident, $c:ident) => {{
        let a = $parser.$a();
        let b = $parser.$b();
        let c = $parser.$c();

        if a != None && b != None && c != None {
            Some((a, b, c))
        } else {
            None
        }
    }};
}
```

Can I combine the second/third rule to one?
And now I am tring use variable marco parameters, but the marco result() is like Some(a, Some(b, c)), or Some(a, Some(b, Some(c, d)))...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can start by writing a macro that accepts any number of arguments:

```
macro_rules! match_token_patten {
    ($parser:ident, $($arg:ident),*)) => {{
        /* macro body */
    }};
}
```

`$($arg:ident),*` will capture any number identifiers, separated by commas.

Next, we need to compute the results for each method. A simple way to do this is to just store them in a tuple, e.g. `(parser.a(), parser.b(), parser.c())`. We'll use `$( ... ),*` syntax again to expand the captured variadic arguments:

```
macro_rules! match_token_patten {
    ($parser:ident, $($arg:ident),*)) => {{
        let results = ( $( $parser.$arg() ),* );
    }};
}
```

Now we want to turn `(Some(x), Some(y), ...)` into a `Some((x, y, ...))`. We can use pattern matching for this! We can write this as:

```
if let (Some(a), Some(b), Some(c)) = results {
    // only if results is a tuple of three Some values
    Some((a, b, c)
} else {
    // at least one of the results is None
    None
}
```

Finally, writing this in the variadic macro form, we get:

```
macro_rules! match_token_pattern {
    ($parser:ident, $($a:ident),*) => {{
        let results = ( $($parser.$a()),* );
        if let ( $(Some($a)),* ) = results {
            Some( ( $($a),* ) )
        } else {
            None
        }
    }};
}
```

Comment: if I pass the save ident to the marco like this: `match_token_pattern!(parser, xxx, xxx)`, it will cause `identifier `xxx` is bound more than once in the same pattern`, how to solve this? any way to generate a different name for the variable?